# Node.js with Express - returning a link to a .CSV file instead of downloading it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, express

I am creating an application that turns json from a database into a csv file and serves it to the user based on selected parameters. Consider the following portion of a router my node server that returns converted CSV data:

```
request(options, function (err, body) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, data: err});
    }
    else {
        var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(body);
        if (jsonresponse.timed_out) {
            return res.status(504).json({ success: true, data: "timed out"});
        }
        else {
            jsonexport(jsonresponse, function(err, data){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                return res.status(200).send(data);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, the above code takes a json response and converts it into csv using [jsonexport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport), then serves the raw csv data to the client.

I know I can use the [file-system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system) module to download the data as a file to local storage before the API call finishes, but is there a way I can create the .csv file and store it somewhere for the client to later access? I want to complete more logic after the API call is finished on the client side before letting the user have the file.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you want [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that seems like a service for the user to upload files to a server? How would I apply this to my use case above?

Comment: My mistake, I misread your question. If you want to save a file and serve it later to a client, you can save it normally to the disk using `fs` and the `express.static()` function to serve the files statically. Read more on that [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you elaborate on how I would serve the response as a file using `express.static()`, I'm having trouble finding examples for serving a csv file myself.

Comment: Sure. I'll submit an answer.

Comment: If you want to store a .csv file for later use you may want to upload the file to AWS S3. You can use `aws-sdk` module to do that. Use `upload()` method of the SDK which will return the download link of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `express.static()` function to accomplish your goal. ([docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html))

Consider the following example:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.use('/files', express.static('/files');
```

This will make it so the `/files` endpoint serves everything inside the `/files` folder statically. Meaning if you have, say, a file called `test.csv` stored in that folder, you could access it through `http://yourhost:port/files/test.csv`.

Comment: Hey Rodrigo, thank you for this. I just had one more question:

How can I send a file to this endpoint from my server, so that I can access it from the client? To clarify my use case, I want to create a csv file and send it to this express endpoint so that I can call it later from the client side.